# El posible significado de "Brigada Tráfico"

Tags: significado-en-contexto

¿Significa algo la frase “Brigada Tráfico” en “[Avenida De Valladolid - Brigada Tráfico](https://moovitapp.com/index/en/public_transit-Avenida_de_Valladolid_Brigada_Trafico-Madrid-site_140068061-21)”? ¿O simplemente es parte del nombre de una parada de autobús? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

La parada está al lado de unas instalaciones de la Policía Municipal, entiendo que de la Brigada de Tráfico.